# Free oracle db instance

Tags: database, oracle10g, create-table

I was looking for a DB instance where  I can try some sql queries(not MYSql) like this ...

```
CREATE TABLE membertable
    (Member_id NUMBER(5) UNIQUE,
     Member_Name VARCHAR2(30),
     Member_Address VARCHAR2(50),
     Acc_Open_Date DATE,
     Membership_type VARCHAR2(20),
     Fees_paid Number(4),
     Max_Books_Allowed Number(2),
     Penalty_Amount Number(7,2)
    );
```

Comment: Get yourself Oracle XE.

Answer (score 2):

if you just want a playpen to try basic sql, use http://sqlfiddle.com/  ?